# DATABASE ERROR: can not output data in datebase [Duplicate entry '0' for key 1]

Tags: php, sql, database

my friend have this query:

```
preg_match_all("#<description>(.*?)</description>#s",$Rss,$message);  
$count = count($message[0]);
$message[0] = str_replace('<description><![CDATA[',' ',$message[0]);
$message[0] = str_replace('</description>]]>',' ',$message[0]);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){    

$db->query("INSERT INTO ".prefix."topicmessage (message,forumid,catid) VALUES ('".$message[0][$i]."','".$MyRows['forumid']."','".forums('CATID',$MyRows['forumid'])."')",__file__,__line__);

}
```

but he qet this database error:

```
DATABASE ERROR: can not output data in datebase [Duplicate entry '0' for key 1] in C:\AppServ\www\ala\Rss_Caller.php on line 57
```

how to fix it??

Comment: Which of those columns is your key for the `topicmessage` table? You either need to verify that it's unique before inserting rows, or (preferably) you need to change it to autoincrement.

Comment: Are you missing `$` in `.."INSERT INTO ".prefix."`?

Comment: Sounds like there is a constraint on one of the columns, I assume its forumid, that prevents duplicates. More than likely it may be the primary key or whatever.

Comment: i edited the code above

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO --> no it fixed by define function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you're trying to insert a record into your database with **0** as a **key value**, this could be a primary key, a secondary key or a unique constraint.

Check the value of the primary key you're inserting, if it's not a programming error, try changing your AUTO_INCREMENT

Hope this helps, don't hesitate to ask further questions =)

Comment: yes , i check it and made it auto increment and it work now,, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a primary key field without autoincrement that you are not giving a value in your query.

probably something like "topicmessageid"

so add an autoincrement to that field.